# Eliminate comma(,) from a column of a Data Table using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I have a `DataTable` as shown below:

[image]

After using below `LINQ` Expression on above DT:

```
if (dt.AsEnumerable().All(row => string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<string>("SameReferences"))))
    BindOldReferences(dt);
else
{
    var grps = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
               let RefID = row.Field<string>("ReferenceID")
               let RefDescription = row.Field<string>("ReferenceDescription")
               let ReferenceUrl = row.Field<string>("ReferenceUrl")
               let SortOrder = row.Field<int>("sortOrder")
               group row by new { RefDescription, ReferenceUrl, SortOrder } into groups
               select groups;

    dt = grps.Select(g =>
    {
        DataRow first = g.First();
        if (first.Field<string>("SameReferences") != null)
        {
            string duplicate = first.Field<int>("SortOrder").ToString();
            first.SetField("SameReferences", string.Format("{0},{1}", duplicate, first.Field<string>("SameReferences")));
         }
        return first;
    }).CopyToDataTable();
}
```

After applying above `LINQ` to DT it becomes :

[image]

**Expected DT** as below : eliminate (,) comma when there is single value in column `Samereferences`. So what changes i have to make to LINQ to get the expected below output.

[image]

Please help..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:-

```
first.SetField("SameReferences", string.Format("{0},{1}", duplicate, 
                first.Field<string>("SameReferences")).Trim(','));
```

It will remove all the trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (first.Field<string>("SameReferences") != null)
{
    string duplicate = first.Field<int>("SortOrder").ToString();
    string sameReference = first.Field<string>("SameReferences");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sameReference))
        first.SetField("SameReferences", duplicate);
    else
        first.SetField("SameReferences", string.Format("{0},{1}", duplicate, sameReference));
}
```